# date time range

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table as follows :-

```
date     time    value 
20120102  900     v1
20120102  901     v2
....................

20120530  1400    vn
```

date and time field combination is primary key.

now I want to select data from a start date time to a end date time for e.g I want to select data from a time stamp 20120102 1000 to date 20120204 930.

one possible solution for this is that I can combine date and time into a single stream and make it primary key but I want to know is there any solution with my existing table structure.

Comment: Why are your storing date and time values like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the time at the ends of the interval separately:

```
NOT (
       `date` < 20120102
    OR `date` > 20120204
    OR ( `date` = 20120102 AND `time` < 1000 )
    OR ( `date` = 20120204 AND `time` >  930 )
)
```